# node.js Project Works on Local Machine, Issues when Deployed on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, web-deployment, web-hosting

I have a node.js + Express project that I've been working on, and it's been working when I run it on my machine. I've set port 4200 for my Express API, with

```
var port = 4200;
```

in app.js

I access the API using axios in React:

```
axios.get('https://localhost:4200/posts ... etc
```

This all works when I run it on my machine, but when I deploy this with Heroku, I get this error:

> GET https://localhost:4200/posts net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>
> Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

How do I fix this?

Comment: i guess you should try changing  https://localhost:4200/posts to heroku domain that you got like XXXXX.herokuapp.com

Comment: I tried replacing every occurence of localhost:4200 with XXXXX.herokuapp.com, but I get a 404 not found whenever I try to access the API now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two thing I would like to highlight:

**1)**
Quoting from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script

> The command in a web process type must bind to the port number specified in the PORT environment variable. If it does not, the dyno will not start.

So what you should do is

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 4200;
```

Now when working on local system port 4200 will be used and when deployed on heroku port assigned by environment variable will be used.

**2)**
From your question you say you are using `axios.get('https://localhost:4200/posts ... etc`. When app is deployed how is it supposed to use `localhost`?

Change localhost to whatever the domain you get when creating app on Heroku.